# What's the difference beetwen "appendfsync everysec" and VM?

Tags: database, redis

What's the difference beetwen "appendfsync everysec" and VM ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Append Only Filesystem (AOF)`, writes a transaction log of every command to Redis in an append only log file. This ensures that if the Redis instance crashes, you can recover all the data up to the crash, at the cost of a large log file.

The `Virtual Memory (VM)` system is a way to increase storage of a Redis system, but potentially swapping unused **values** to disk. The default (non-VM) operation of Redis is to store **everything** in RAM, however the VM system allows you to potentially store a bit more data in RAM by swapping values out of RAM - note the keys will always be stored in RAM for fast access.

So, but features are orthogonal - one is a way to persist information, and another is a way to increase memory storage of a Redis system.

Comment: Hm. I think you aren't right. You are talking about always AOF option. It is quote from /etc/redis.conf 
# always: fsync after every write to the append only log . Slow, Safest.
# everysec: fsync only if one second passed since the last fsync. Compromise.

Comment: I'm not clear on what part isn't correct - can you expand? According to http://redis.io/topics/persistence you turn on AOF by setting `appendonly yes` and then control the different fsync options to to the AOF file (to use always, everysec, or never). *However*, my point is that AOF is completely different to VM - one is a way to persist, another is a way to expand data storage within Redis.

Comment: > The Append Only Filesystem (AOF), writes a transaction log of every command to Redis in an append only log file. This will be only if you configure "appendfsync always". I ask about "appendfsync everysec".

Comment: Okay, but whether it's always or everysec - both are completely different to the VM option, which is what the original question asked.

Comment: I know that AOF everysec is different to VM. I dont know what's difference (: